# iOS: LocalNotification and Background recording not mixing

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudioplayer, uilocalnotification, avaudiorecorder

So I am experiencing something strange on my iPhone (iOS7/iPhone 5s).

Basically what I am doing is an event will happen when the app will be in the background that will make it start recording. This all works fine and I have tested it. However, I want to give the user a localnotification so if they have vibrates/sounds enabled they can hear that it has begun recording.

BUT when I do that it seems like the notification gets cut off by the recording and the recording does not even start.

Here is some parts of my code. If you need more let me know.

In ViewDidLoad

```
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];

// Start recording
[self setupRecording];


- (void)setupRecording {
//////////////// GET AUDIO STUFF SET UP ///////////////////////
// Set the audio file

NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath_ = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];

    NSString *pathToSave = [documentPath_ stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TEMP.m4a"];
// File URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToSave];//FILEPATH];


// Setup audio session
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

// Define the recorder setting
NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

// Initiate and prepare the recorder
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:nil];
recorder.delegate = self;

[recorder prepareToRecord];

recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

}

```
- (void)localNotification {

UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tapadoodledo is now recording."];
localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}



- (void)record {
self.startDate = [NSDate date];
self->timeRecording = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[self.recordingIndicatorButton setTitle:@"Stop recording" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];

[recorder record];
NSTimer *TimerUpdate = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1
                                                        target:self selector:@selector(timerTask) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[self setRecording];
}

- (void)stopRecording {
[self.recordingIndicatorButton setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self->timeRecording invalidate];
[longTimer invalidate];
self.timeRecordingLabel.text = @   "";

// Stop recording
[recorder stop];

[self moveRecordingToCorrectTime];
[self setListening];
}
```

And here is the code that gets called in the background when an event happens:

```
- (void)longTimer:(NSTimer *)timer1
{
if (count >= 2) {
    if (self->recording) {
//            [self localNotification];
//            [self stopRecording];
              [self localNotification];
    } else {
 //            [self localNotification];
//            [self record];
    }
}
first = YES;
count = 0;
}
```

What I find is if I comment out the [self record], the localnotifications work perfectly, and if I comment out the localnotifications, the recorder works perfectly, but when both together I get problems (Does not always record)

WHAT I notice is that sometimes the zibrate does not happen when it's calling record IF I have it calling the record function as well BUT it will vibrate if I remove the call to record. But it always vibrates for the stop recording, even if I have that call to stopRecording.

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, but I did the following and it 'works'. ALthough I am still curious why it is doing this.

```
            [self localNotification];
        double delayInSeconds = 0.2;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self record];

        });
```